# ionic storage.get undefined

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

```
ionic info
```

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v8.11.0
npm  : 5.6.0 
OS   : macOS High Sierra
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

MyProvider

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalTokenProvider {

  constructor(public storage: Storage) {
    console.log('Hello GlobalTokenProvider Provider');
  }
  getToken() {
      let token;
      this.storage.get('token').then(data => token  = data);
      return token
    }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
    import { GlobalTokenProvider } from '../providers/global-token/global-token';
      providers: [
    ...
    GlobalTokenProvider,
    ...
  ]
```

usepage.ts

```
import { GlobalTokenProvider } from '../../providers/global-token/global-token';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public http:HttpClient,public storage:Storage,public globaltoken:GlobalTokenProvider) {
alert(this.globaltoken.getToken())
  }
```

this storage have token but provider return undefined
how to use storage in provider

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Your Provider just return storage as promise

```
getToken(){
   return this.storage.get('token')
}
```

In your usepage.ts retrieve like this

```
this.globaltoken.getToken().then((token)=>{
  console.log(token)
})
```

Comment: and potentially don't forget to wait for storage.ready (this.storage.ready().then...)

Comment: @Abinesh thanks for the comment, that was the problem in my question :D +1